# deploying on azure vm

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, azure

I was trying to deploy a backend app to azure vm and tried to access the same through the public ip but i was not able to access it. i tried the same in AWS, it works.

Now,what i did:

•created a VM and EC2 with RHEL8

•installed node and git and used git clone to clone my github repo

•did npm install and npm run, app is successfully running in both VMs

•port 22(SSH), 80(HTTP) and 3000(my application is running in this port) all are open

after this when i use the public ip of my AWS EC2 as url (public ip:3000) i can view my app. but when i try the same with Azure VM, it is not showing anything. i have tried even removing the ':3000' but it is still not working. can someone please help me out?

Comment: I don't see any information anywhere about opening firewalls. You need to open all firewalls (windows, Azure) on that port to allow external clients to connect.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid how do i open firewall in linux, im using rhel 8?

Comment: I don't know how to open a firewall in rhel 8. I would just google it and I suggest you do the same. Then you need to ensure the actual Azure VM itself has open firewalls. This is probably the difference between AWS and Azure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal

Comment: i will look into this..thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks a lot, it worked. i had to open port 3000 from inside the linux vm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should test it first using the browser in your VM, and address localhost.

If that works, then it is a firewall problem. You then need to open port 3000.

If you are using http then removing ":3000" is the same as replacing it with ":80".

Comment: actually im using a linux vm in azure(rhel 8) so i cant check it in browser and i have opened port 3000,80 and 22. still it is not working

Comment: Do you have a way to check that your application is running on the VM?

Comment: yes, i can ssh to the vm and do npm start and there it shows app is running successfully

Comment: Then it is the ports that are not open

Comment: i had to open the port 3000 from inside the linux. thanks a lot

Comment: Rather than marking this question as correct, please post more details on what you did. Regardless if it worked on AWS, the port must have already been opened there.